# How to move items smoothly in wxPython?

Tags: drag-and-drop, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to drag and drop a button, with the following code in wxPython, however, the drag flickers, and feels jarring, and I'm not sure why -- or how to fix it. I've pored over the wxWidgets docs, but can't seem to find out what the problem is. Thanks in advance!

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
d = {}

def wMouseDown(e):
    print "!!!", e.GetEventObject()

def MouseDown(e):   
    o           = e.GetEventObject()
    sx,sy       = panel.ScreenToClient(o.GetPositionTuple())
    dx,dy       = panel.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
    o._x,o._y   = (sx-dx, sy-dy)
    d['d'] = o

def MouseMove(e):
    try:
        if 'd' in d:
            o = d['d']
            x, y = wx.GetMousePosition()
            o.SetPosition(wx.Point(x+o._x,y+o._y))
    except: pass

def MouseUp(e):
    try:
        if 'd' in d: del d['d']
    except: pass

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple.py')
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
button1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "foo")
box.Add(button1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
button2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "bar")
box.Add(button2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

button1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, MouseDown)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, MouseDown)

button1.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, MouseMove)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, MouseMove)

button1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, MouseUp)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, MouseUp)

panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, MouseMove)
panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, MouseUp)

panel.SetSizer(box)
panel.Layout()
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It's smooth on windows with wxPython 2.9

Comment: Entirely so? You can't detect any irritating effects?

Comment: None at all, and I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Try explicitly calling panel.Update() after each move, maybe your underlying gui toolkit is trying to optimize (minimize) redrawing.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that...but it still acts funny. The button "wobbles" slightly under the mouse cursor as it moves, and it's driving me insane!

Comment: @FrobbaBobba It is also working smoothly on windows 8 pro with wxPython v3.0